# Последовательные ajax-запросы конвертировать в параллельные

Tags: javascript, java, android, ajax

В ходе работы на outsource, я вынужденно сталкнулся с недружелюбным кодом, дружелюбно разложенным другим программистом в прошлом... К делу.

android проект написан с помощью кардобы (webView-шная прослойка). При авторизации выполняеся 4 вложенных друг в друга запроса. Делается это средствами ajax, каждый следующий запрос дополняет результат первого запроса т.е.объекта data. По комерческим причинам, я не могу привести сюда сходный код, да и вряд ли бы вам было на него приятно смотреть. Но я приведу симметричную конструкцию:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: 60000,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        error: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof data.id == 'undefined') {
                // ....
            } else {
                // load more user infos
                $.ajax({
                    url: url2,
                    type: 'GET',
                    timeout: 60000,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    error: function (data) {
                        // ...
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        data.***** = ****;
                        // далее еще два запроса

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Меня интересует шкурный вопрос: можно ли от этого как-то избавиться? Есть ли возможность распараллелить это средствами ajax? Моя интуиция говорит, о необходимости изменения серверной стороны. Запрос должен быть 1, со всеми полями сразу. Но мб есть способ заставить эти 4 запроса работать парарлельно, модифицируя 1 объект? Скромно прошу не бить меня за такой код, он не мой...

**Дополнение № 1**

Поле id из объекта data (результат запроса № 1) действительно используется для всех остальнызх запросов. Ноо... 2, 3 и 4 запросы не связаны друг с другом. Они сложены друг в друга только с целью модифицирования общего объекта  data (насколько я могу судить). Мне интересно, можно ли 2-3-4 запросы пустить в отдельные потоки так, чтобы они модифицировали 1 общий объект. Success 4-го запроса заканчивается такой строчкой =)

```
that.user = data;
```

Может быть есть другие варианты?

Comment: ставлю на то, что это сделано потому, что первый запрос забирает необходимую часть данных для второго запроса и так далее.. просто так никто не выстраивает такую лестницу из запросов

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич дополнил вопрос

Comment: я думаю вы можете все запросы(после 2) асинхронно вызывать, если изменения `data` не последовательны и не являются следствием предыдущего вызова. Вы можете вызвать в теле 1-го запроса все остальные.

Comment: "модифицирования общего объекта data" - `data` в приведенном коде - параметр обработчика `success`. Это всегда разные объекты.

Comment: @Igor по замечанию Игоря, посмотрел в теле последнего запроса есть строка that.user = data; Полагаю это глобальная переменная =)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич могли бы вы кинуть ссылку на пример, как это обработать. Я слишком плохо знаком с js, можно сказать я чувствую себя рыбой на берегу)

Comment: смысл фразы "тело последнего запроса"  известен только Вам. Не темните, а покажите весь код.

Comment: @Igor я имею ввиду обработку по success - это я обозвал телом запрос. Согласен не корректно приведение. Запрос показать не могу, извините

Comment: тут вот какой вопрос, `this.user = data` должен выполнить только после окончаниях ВСЕХ запросов? Просто по сути 4 запрос может выполниться раньше, чем 3. Поэтому, возможно, сделана последовательность

Comment: Данный код для авторизации предназначен ?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич да

Comment: Я почти уверен, если это авторизация, то ‘this.user = data” цепляет все данные по пользователю а дальше идут манипуляции с данными

Comment: @ThisMan я думаю, что можно после 1 запроса сделать `that.user = data`, а затем добавлять к объекту поля: что-то вроде that.user.programm = programm;

Comment: ну тогда просто в `success` первом вызывайте остальные запросы и все

Comment: Ну я там и написал в начале)) @ThisMan Потому что тут 2 варианта всего - либо все запросы специально так выстроены, потому что логика запросов цепная, либо действительно просто кто-то решил построить лестницу... но без полного кода это не узнать

Comment: @ThisMan в rx java есть zip который позволяет объеденить пачку запросов, с одним общий обработчиком. В идеале я вижу такое же решение для ajax.

Comment: Если вы используете `ajax`, возможно можете использовать `Promise`, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так далее... простите за неполный код, пишу с телефона, но вы поняли принцип, если там нету зависимостей от манипуляций данными в каждом запросе.

```
 $.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
timeout: 60000,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
error: function () {

},
success: function (data) {
    if (typeof data.id == 'undefined') {
        // ....
    } else {
        // load more user infos
        $.ajax({
            url: url2,
            type: 'GET',
            timeout: 60000,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            error: function (data) {
                // ...
            },
            success: function (data) {
                data.***** = ****;
                // далее еще два запроса

            }
        });
$.ajax({
            url: url3,
            type: 'GET',
            timeout: 60000,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            error: function (data) {
                // ...
            },
            success: function (data) {
                data.***** = ****;
                // далее еще два запроса

            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: да, именно так я и попробовал) но пока е взлетело

Comment: Тогда это нужно смотреть что у вас в теле запросов, потому что подозреваю, что это не просто так сделано!

Comment: Какой смысл в этих строчках `data.***** = ****;`? Параметр `data` не живет дольше вызова анонимной функции (если только не присваивается какой-то внешней переменной). А здесь еще и несколько перекрытых `data` в области видимости.

Comment: @igor это я оставил потому что с телефона пишу. Тяжело и стереть и пост сделать корректно :(

Comment: а-а-а, это копия кода из вопроса

Comment: @Igor именно, я сразу извинился перед автором, и указал, что это сработает, если нету связи последовательной между 2 -> 3 -> 4... запросами, а если есть прямая зависимость в преобразованиях, то только полный код поможет разобраться!